# MS SQL Server 2017 for Linux - Installing to non default paths

Tags: linux

I want to install SQL Server 2017 for Linux on RHEl7.4.. but I want to use LVM to create a series of volumes for each of the important volumes.

/mssql/EBSData 
/mssql/EBSLogs 
blah blah blah

Is there a way to do this without mounting the volumes, symlinking the paths, then installing?

I'd assumed the installer might have had additional args/flags to change the default installation path, but doesn't seem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables to control this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-environment-variables.  When you run the `mssql-conf` utility (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf) it will pick up these values and configure them for you.

This will allow you to change your directories:

- [Default data directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#datadir)
- [Default log directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#datadir)
- [Default dump directory (memory dumps etc)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#dumpdir)
- [Default backup directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-configure-mssql-conf#backupdir)

and more.

Comment: Thank you for going into detail.... I seem to have skipped this part of the documentation